# how to use schedule variables in builders in luntbuild?

Tags: continuous-integration, build-automation, luntbuild

We are using Luntbuild 1.6.2 as a build automation tool.

Builders using `ant` are defined for different tasks with various `parameters`.

Schedules are defined over one or more builders. Since the builders are re-used so it is definitely better to have variable defined in schedules itself which can be used in builders.

Can anyone guide me how to define `variable` at `schedule` level which can be accessed at `builder` level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I was able to get to this...

While creating the `schedule` the variable can be defined in the variable section.

```
myVariable=myValue
```

and in the `builder` the `OGNL` expression which is required to access the schedule variable is

```
${build.schedule.var["myVariable"]}
```